# Whether $[0, 1)$ is closed in the lower limit topology

Tags: general-topology

Let T be the smallest topology on $\mathbb R $ which contains all sets of the type $ [a,b)$ where $ a,b \in \mathbb R $ and all sets of type $[a,b)$ are open in T .Determine if the set $[0,1)$ is closed in this topology.

Here is my work:
The closure of $[0,1)$ in this topology is $[0,1)$ We can do this because , 
if we take an open set  $ u= [1,\epsilon)$ , $\epsilon > 1$ then $ 1\in u $ but $ u\cap [0,1) = \phi$  ,so $1$ is not an adherent point of $[0,1)$ ,therefore all the points other than 1  of $[0,1)$  are adherent points.
We know a set is closed iff and it contains all its adherent points.

I am not cent percent sure on my work.
Can anyone give a look over it?

Comment: How can $[0,1)\cap [0,\varepsilon)=\emptyset$ when one interval is contained in the other?

Comment: Hint: Open intervals $(a,b)$ are also open in the lower-limit topology.

Comment: I am sorry , I meant $[1,\epsilon)$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Can you show that the complement of $[0,1)$, which is $(-\infty,0)\cup [1,\infty)$, is a union of open sets, hence open?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint* If the topology contains all sets of the form $[a,b)$, gluing $[a,a+1),[a+1,a+2),\ldots$ up gives all sets of the form $[a,\infty)$ are open. Similarily, all sets $(-\infty,b)$ are open, for they are unions $\cdots\cup [b-2,b-1)\cup [b-1,b)$.

Comment: why (-inf, b] is open ? I didn't follow.

Comment: @Siddharth Corrected.